\newcommand syntax with callouts
I suspect I am just missing something minor, but thought perhaps someone could assist.
I am using a Markdown file with the Eisvogel template. I am using both awesomebox and fontawesome5 packages to create callouts. I would prefer having the LaTeX code in the Eisvogel template so as to keep most everything simple Markdown.
Here is the existing code (a question and answer) followed by my /newcommand in my Markdown file.
\awesomebox[maroon]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{maroon}{\textbf{Question:} What flags in the output state what virtualization support is available on this server?}

\awesomebox[brandgreen]{2pt}{\faLightbulb}{brandgreen}{\textbf{Answer:} Multiple flags show up: \texttt{Virtualization: VT-x}, \texttt{Hypervisor vendor: KVM}, and \texttt{Virtualization type: full}. These flags provide information about the type of virtualization support available on this server.}

\question{This is a question.}

\answer{This is an answer.}

This is how I added the code to the Eisvogel template:
%% Testing newcommands, question and answers
\newcommand{\question}[1][\textbf{Question:} ]{\awesomebox[maroon]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{maroon}{#1}}
\newcommand{\answer}[1][{Answer:} ]{\awesomebox[brandgreen]{2pt}{\faLightbulb}{brandgreen}{#1}}

And here is how my first two working examples appear (LaTeX in Markdown) and the next two are my attempts (using the \newcommand with the LaTeX moved to the Eisvogel template).

My question is this:
Is there any simple way I can get my questions to appear inside the code block?
Thanks in advance.

You should tag your questions with pandoc instead of latex3

Please provide a full markdown example. It's really hard to just guess, what you are doing

Thank you for the suggestions. Apologies as I am not a frequent visitor. However, I did figure it out. I'll post my answer below.

Here is how I fixed my issue:
In the Eisvogel.tex file I added the following lines of code:
%% Testing newcommands, question and answers
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\awesomebox[maroon]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{maroon}{#1}}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\awesomebox[brandgreen]{2pt}{\faLightbulb}{brandgreen}{#1}}

Next, in my Markdown file I added the following lines:
\awesomebox[maroon]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{maroon}{\textbf{Question:} What flags in the output state what virtualization support is available on this server?}

\awesomebox[brandgreen]{2pt}{\faLightbulb}{brandgreen}{\textbf{Answer:} Multiple flags show up: \texttt{Virtualization: VT-x}, \texttt{Hypervisor vendor: KVM}, and \texttt{Virtualization type: full}. These flags provide information about the type of virtualization support available on this server.}

\question{Question: This is a question.}

\answer{Question: This is an answer.}

And this is the final outcome, exactly as I wanted it:

Nothing more was required in the eisvogel template or in Markdown. This code should work after running the pandoc build script:
#!/bin/bash
time -p pandoc \
    L0.md \
    L1.md \
    -o LabTest.pdf \
    --from markdown \
    --toc \
    --toc-depth 2 \
    --filter=pandoc-latex-environment \
    --template "eisvogel-lg.tex" \
    --number-sections \
    --listings

